# Javascript promises: how to deal with token expiry in API calls?

Tags: javascript, promise

When I am receiving an error from my API that my token has expired I want to be able to re-issue a new token and repeat the request as first sent without the user feeling any difference. Is there a way to handle this use case elegantly?

```
function relogin(userInfo) {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    });
}

function makeTransaction(token, options) {
    dataOperations.makeTransaction(token, options).then(function (result) {
        // notify ui - new data yey!
    }).catch(function (err) {
        if (err.code === 304) {
            relogin.then(function (token) {
                makeTransaction(token, options);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                // notify UI - problems with server
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, explicitly asking for a third-party library for something is considered off-topic here.  But, you can show what you have done so far, describe where you got stuck and ask how to solve the problem.

Comment: It is good to know. I went through the "How do I ask a good question?" manual to refresh my memory of the best practices when asking a question. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that code looks pretty good already.  what specifically is your issue?  If you have many transactions and you're worried about code duplication, and checking for HTTP 304 many times, you could wrap your transactions in a handler:

```
function relogin(userInfo) {
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // ...
  });
}

function myTask(params) {
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // ...
  });
}

function doTask(fn, context, params) {
  return fn.apply(context, params).then(function(results) {
    return results;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    if (err.code === 304) {
      return relogin({}).then(doTask(fn, context, params));
    }
    else {
      return err;
    }
  });
}

// ...

$("#foo").on("click", function(e) {
  doTask(myTask, this, params).done(function(results) {
    alert("all done");
  }).catch(function(err) {
      alert(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: This can loop infinitely on 304's... would want to add a max number of retries.